# Zero due to ESR in buck converter

Tags: buck

[image]

How come the equation given leads to one answer for the zero location (marked 1) whereas my intuition leads to another (marked 2)

Comment: It seems a typo. Is there any supporting text/formulas in the book leading up to, or derived from, this equation? Also please cite the image source.

Comment: Nothing that leads up to it explicitly. Power Management techniques for integrated circuits by Ke Horng Chen

Comment: You have correctly determined the time constant for a *nulled* output voltage which is \$\tau=r_CC_{out}\$. The denominator is thus \$N(s)=1+s\tau\$ and the zero is \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{\tau}=\frac{1}{r_CC_{out}}\$. This is a typo in the final expression which is, by the way, incomplete as it does not include the ESR(s) in the denominator expression while it does in the numerator.